router.project-osrm.org is giving 500 and 504 Gateway Time-out errors
router.project-osrm.org using this for distance and using curl and sending a request to the URL
https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/6.7685546,51.2874675;6.0907987,50.7681629?steps=false&alternatives=false

This URL was working for a long time, but today it stopped working.

That URL worked for me. If it's a site you manage and you're getting 500, you'll need to do some troubleshooting. If it's not a site you manage and you're getting errors from their site, you'll need to contact them.

In which browser you tested ?and from where ?

I tested with Chrome in the Carolinas, US. However, this morning it's not coming up for me. Firefox gave "An error occurred during a connection to router.project-osrm.org. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR", and Chrome gave "504 Gateway Time-Out"
